# Hide or show specific step from React TourProvider based on user's device

Tags: reactjs

Does anyone know if it is posible to hide or show an specific step from React TourProvider based on user's screen size or device (dekstop or mobile)? I'm trying to show different steps based on the user's device, as the elements may render different because of the responsivnes of the screen. I've tried doing the following to find out the size of the screen:

```
import { useMediaQuery } from '@material-ui/core';

const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(max-width: 991px)');

{
  (!onPreview) ?
 <div className={`${isMobile ? "mobile-login-create" : ""} ${"showmenu"}`} onClick={menuHandler}><i className="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          : ""
      }
```

indeed the class mobile-login-create (which is one of the selectors from the array of objects of the list of steps I'm trying to display in my page) is getting hide or shown based in isMobile as I checked on the Google Chrome dev tools. However, even though the class is being removed or not from the specified div, the step I need to hide, remains showing on the page. I also tried to find something on the documentacion https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reactour/tour regarding my question, but I had no luck.

```
import { useMediaQuery } from '@material-ui/core';

const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(max-width: 991px)');

{
  (!onPreview) ?
 <div className={`${isMobile ? "mobile-login-create" : ""} ${"showmenu"}`} onClick={menuHandler}><i className="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          : ""
      }
```

Comment: This is an incomplete question as you are not showing the actual steps .. BUT it is simple.  Just build out your `steps = [` array and use your ternary just like you did in your element using `{(isMobile) ? { ... .. ..` to exclude the step you want to not show.